# kubectl deployment.yaml permission denied

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I am using Amazon EKS and I need to create the `deployment.yaml` file in order to generate the configuration for kubernetes with the following command:

```
(sudo) kubectl create deployment kafkaconsumer --image=xx/xxx --dry-run -o=yaml > deployment.yaml
```

but when I run it it returns me

```
deployment.yaml: Permission denied
```

I don't know why it doesn't work, I had previously used it in another project under the same conditions and it worked well.

Comment: It seems that it's not failing to create the deployment on k8s, but the `deployment.yaml` file itself. Do you have permissions to write in that loication? if you try `touch deployment.yaml` do you also get an error?

Comment: you were right, I did not have write permissions on the folder, now it works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the command isn't failing to create the deployment on k8s, but the file `deployment.yaml` itself.

Raise your permissions and try to run the command again, the problem will be solved.